# IE9: SVG Serialization and "No such interface supported" when calling serializeToString( )

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have some `.svg` files that I want to convert to string format. I'm running into some issues with IE9. I know it supports SVGs.

**SVG:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="42" height="42" viewBox="0 0 42 42" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="arrow" stroke="#b2bbbe" stroke-width="3">
          <g transform="translate(14.000000, 7.000000)">
              <path d="M0,0 L14.8731048,14.25 L0,28.5"/>
          </g>
      </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.get(imgURL, function(data) {
    //Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
    var $svg = $(data).find('svg');

    //Create new XMLSerializer
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();

    //Serialize the response
    var svg_str = serializer.serializeToString($svg[0]);
}, 'xml');
```

Works so far in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but inside IE9, I get this error:

```
SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported
```

I'm not sure if it's the AJAX call, or something else that is causing this to happen. I checked the IE documentation, and it seems this function is supported...

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/15/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Any ideas as to why this is IE is spewing out this error message?

---

**Update:**
I scaled back and tested this with no AJAX request, and IE9 did not throw the error and everything ran correctly. The smaller test is as follows:

```
//Manually inject the SVG code inline into the <body>
$('body').append('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg id="test" width="42" height="42" viewBox="0 0 42 42" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="avatarjs_text-forward-svg" stroke="#b2bbbe" stroke-width="3"><g id="text-change-btn" transform="translate(14.000000, 7.000000)"><path d="M0,0 L14.8731048,14.25 L0,28.5"/></g></g></g></svg>');

//Grab the SVG
var ts = $('svg#test');

//Create serializer and serialize the string
var se = new XMLSerializer();
var str = se.serializeToString(ts[0]);
```

So is there some connection between IE9's AJAX handling and the issue I'm getting with the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using using the `.xml` property of the returned XML typed data instead for IE9.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: imgURL,
    dataType: 'xml',
}).done(function(data) {
    var $svg       = $(data).find('svg'),
        serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
        svg_str;

    //If an error is thrown then we just grab the 
    //.xml property of the returned data.               
    try{
        svg_str = serializer.serializeToString($svg[0]);
    } catch(e) {
        svg_str = $svg[0].xml;
    }

    //Do stuff here with string
    doStuffWithString(svg_str);
});
```

I ended up using a try-catch block instead of checking against whether `window.XMLSerializer` or `window.XMLSerializer.serializeToString` was `undefined`. They both are defined. In the end, not sure if this is the best solution. So, I'd still love to hear any other solutions out there, or even more so why IE9 was throwing that error.